# How to start and stop SAP instances (including databases) automatically with OS boot and shutdown, respectively?

Tags: systemd, automation, sap, sles12

Running SLES15 (uses systemd), how can I make SAP instances and databases start automatically on system boot, and stop them properly on system shutdown or reboot?

[One example I found](https://blogs.sap.com/2016/06/07/auto-startstop-of-hdb-and-sap-on-reboot/) is for the obsolete LSB start mechanism.

Comment: Maybe someone with higher reputation create a "sles15" tag, please! I had to use tag "sles12".

Comment: To start a service  like SAP on boot and stopping it again with SLWS 15 and systemd is not really rocket science. You just need to deploy and enable  one or more *"systemd service unit"*  files. See https://documentation.suse.com/sles/15-SP1/html/SLES-all/cha-systemd.html - https://blogs.sap.com/2021/08/12/using-systemd-to-start-stop-sap-services-on-suse-linux/

Comment: The thing is that systemd required "reasonable" (definition a matter of taste) programs, that SAP programs hardly fulfill. In short. I know what a systemd unit is, but what are the proper commands to run?

Comment: How do you start/stop/restart program, databases currently? Use it to move it to systemd. Here is a example and good start [link](https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc/?id=000019672). Try it and come with the results.

Comment: There is the obsolete `startsap`/`stopsap` that still works and the "modern" `sapcontrol` that is harder to use (mostly because it's asynchronous).